# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'. Android Studio Update

Tags: android

I Just updated Android Studio. I now cannot load any of my Projects.

I get the below error

A problem occurred configuring root project 'Test'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.4.2
> project : > com.android.library:com.android.library.gradle.plugin:7.4.2
> > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.4.2' but:
> - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.4.2')
> - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.4.2')
> - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.4.2')
> - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.4.2')

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had same problem.
This is how i fixed it

Set your gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to 7.4 like this
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip`

and your build.gradle to version 7.3.0

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.0' apply false
```

Add1:
Take in mind that this is temporary solution.
Issue was reported to Android studio issue-tracker multiple times and one user came with this solution.
I do credit the user who found the solution here : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/274681084

Comment: To whoever marked/s the post as not useful, at least explain why. This temp fix had worked for me and for couple of other people.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps

1. Open Android Studio.
2. Click on "File" in the top menu bar.
3. Go to "Settings" (or "Preferences" on macOS).
4. In the Settings/Preferences dialog, expand the `Build, Execution, Deployment` category.
5. Select `Build Tools` and then choose `Gradle.`
6. In the "Gradle" settings, you'll find an option for `Use gradle from.` By default, it's set to `wrapper` Change it to "Specified location."
7. Next to the "Specified location" option, you can browse and set the path to your preferred Gradle distribution. In your case, you should set it to the desired Gradle location, like `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr`.
8. Click "Apply" and then "OK" to save the changes.

After making these changes, Android Studio will use the specified Gradle location as the default for new projects you create. This way, you can ensure that the Gradle distribution you want is consistently used in your projects.

Comment: incomplete solution for Mac. Thanks though